# Maintain 'Current Balance' in DDD Aggregate

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design

Working on an Inventory system.

Using C# and Entity Framework.

A **StockItem** will have many **StockMovement**s.  **StockMovement**s could be a Purchase, Sale, Return, Wastage, etc.

A **StockItem** therefore has a **StockLevel**.

What is the best way to maintain **StockLevel** for a **StockItem**?

One way would be to just SUM all **StockMovements** when querying the **StockItem**, but if the number of **StockMovements** becomes excessive, it seems perhaps better to maintain a **StockLevel** on the **StockItem** and adjust it each time a **StockMovement** is added.

However, if two separate clients are processing a **StockMovement** at the same time, there is the possibility that two instance of the **StockItem** are materialised at the same time (i.e. both show balance of 100 units).

Client 1 removes 10 units and Client 2 also removes 10 units, but when updating the **StockLevel**, both **StockItem** instances will adjust the new **StockLevel** to 90, which is wrong.  Should be 80.

So, using Optimistic Concurrency seems one option, but I don't want to push this back to the user.

Does it make sense for the Application layer to capture the concurrency exception and then retry on behalf of the client or are there any better patterns I should adopt?

Comment: "Does it make sense for the Application layer to capture the concurrency exception and then retry on behalf of the client or are there any better patterns I should adopt?"

Oh yes, that absolutely makes sense -- very common approach.

Answer (score 1):

Use EF Core's [Concurrency Tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/concurrency?tabs=data-annotations)

Mark `StockLevel` as `[ConcurrencyCheck]`, catch `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` as shown in [Resolving concurrency conflicts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency#resolving-concurrency-conflicts)

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Interesting approach.  Am actually more inclined refresh unit of work using ChangeTracker.Clear and re-run the command from the application layer.  The aggregate is small and logic is trivial in my case.  The Command object can be marked as "AutoRetryableOnDbConcurrencyException" when I don't want to push back to client and the CommandHandler can inspect this to decide whether to refresh the unit of work again and re-run the command or throw back to client.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Better to re-run, less code ;) This documentation was created when EF Core was not exposing `ChangeTracker.Clear` method.

Answer (score 0):

you can use redis lock, because redis was single-threaded, just one request  can processing for StockItem in the same time